# geom_cols shows incorrect y-Values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've started using R a few months ago and am currently trying to create some plots for my first real-life dataset.

I am trying to visualize the relationship between Reaction time and a categorical within-subjects variable (whether a symbol belonged to yourself or a stranger). I.e. every participant has seen both symbols and given several responses to each, which are summarized in a participant rt mean.

Sample from the dataset (it actually has some more colums, which is why every participant pops up 3 times). If I plot the entire dataset, the problem persists, but I left it out here to avoid overcomplicating it.

```
participant Assignment rt_mean

         <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
 1     7148832 Yourself      601.
 2     7148832 Yourself      554.
 3     7148832 Yourself      604.
 4     7148832 Stranger      810.
 5     7148832 Stranger      821.
 6     7148832 Stranger      712.
 7     7148833 Yourself      651.
 8     7148833 Yourself      725.
 9     7148833 Yourself      784.
10     7148833 Stranger      693.
```

The problem is that the bar chart ggplot2::geom_col() produces don't match the actual means of the data:

```
mean_yourself = mean(dplyr::filter(reaction_time, Assignment == "Yourself")$rt_mean)
mean_stranger = mean(dplyr::filter(reaction_time, Assignment == "Stranger")$rt_mean)`
```

Returns:
mean_yourself = 686.2
mean_stranger = 749.3

However, using the same data to do a plot with geom_cols:

```
reaction_time_plot <- reaction_time %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = Assignment, y = rt_mean)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "Assignment", y = "Reaction Time in ms") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ABB0B8",
                               "#4C4E52"))
reaction_time_plot
```

Returns the following plot:

[image: Bar Plot]

This clearly cannot be correct, as (a) the direction of bars has reversed compared to the means I've calculated here and confirmed to be correct in SPSS (Yourself has a smaller mean than Stranger) and (b) the numbers on the scale don't match the means, they appear to be a bit higher than the actual means. Also, using other kinds of plot in the same code gives the correct means (e.g. boxplot)

```
reaction_time_plot <- reaction_time %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = Assignment, y = rt_mean)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "Assignment", y = "Reaction Time in ms") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ABB0B8",
                               "#4C4E52"))
reaction_time_plot
```

[image: boxplot of same data]

I would be very grateful for any tips as to what is going wrong here

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a sample of the data to allow the others to reproduce your code. You can use `dput(your_data)` and copy-paste the result.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This is my first post ever :)

Comment: `geom_col` is the same as `geom_bar(stat="identity")`. If you want the bar plot to plot the mean for each group, use `geom_bar(stat="summary")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, especially to Adam Quek for the correct solution!

"geom_col is the same as geom_bar(stat="identity"). If you want the bar plot to plot the mean for each group, use geom_bar(stat="summary") instead"